# bat to sh translation please

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file

Alright so I'm not very great with .sh and .bat scripting, but I need to translate a .bat file to .sh and was hoping I could get some help here .

File name is booyaka.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
:START
REM what to put below:
REM perl m2auto.pl user pass wait chartype "Lord Stealer"
REM wait = 0.0 for most
REM chartype: 1 = agimage, 2 = fighter, 3 = mage, 4 = Pure Fighter
REM stealer must have full name
perl m3.pl user password 0.0 1 "Stealer"
perl -e sleep(2)
goto START
```

Thats what my script looks like currently, but for some reason when I try ./booyaka.sh in terminal it returns the following: bash: ./booyaka.sh: No such file or directory

If I navigate within the directory that the file is stored in and try executing from there it returns this: bash: ./booyaka.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Any insight as to what I'm doing incorrectly ?

Comment: It originated from a batch file and I dont know how to entirely translate it, could you provide any more information ?

Comment: Don't translate a `.bat` file, but write a `.sh` shell script from scratch.... Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) ...

Comment: Once you have the script translated, you have some other things to fix: You have windows carriage returns in the file instead of UNIX. Change with your editor or look up how to do it with the `tr` command. Also check the permissions on the file and do `chmod u+x` if necessary. You can also create a `scripts` folder which is part of your defined `$PATH`, and put the script there so it will be found from any directory and not just its own.

Answer (score 5):

## Comments

In batch files, comments are indicated using `REM`. In Bash, they're indicated with a `#`:

```
# This is a comment!
```

## Loops

Your batch file implements a loop using a label and a `GOTO`. Bash has more structured loops. In your case, you probably want a `while` loop:

```
while true; do
    # stuff
done
```

## Simple commands

In batch files, you just write the command. It's the same in Bash. You can leave your `perl` lines untouched.

## Line endings

Batch files use DOS line endings (`CRLF`). As far as I know, Bash doesn't really care, but for the first line (a comment to Bash), the **operating system** does. Your first line must be terminated UNIX-style with an `LF` and no `CR`.

Comment: @user2926415: In your batch file, you start with `:START`. This is where you will return to. You end it with `goto START`, returning back to the start. Obviously, the inside bit will be repeated multiple times. To do that in Bash, you don't use `goto`s, but rather surround the bit to be repeated with `while true; do` above and `done` below.

Comment: @user2926415: Yes; replace `:START` with `while true; do` and `goto START` with `done`.

Comment: @user2926415: Oops! `sleep(2)` needs to be in quotes, like `"sleep(2)"`. You could also opt to replace the whole `perl -e sleep(2)` line with `sleep 2`.

Comment: @user2926415: No. `perl -e sleep(2)` needs to be replaced with either `perl -e "sleep(2)"` or `sleep 2`. They both do the same thing; one goes to Perl to sleep, the other has Bash sleep without having Perl involved at all.

Comment: The script ran the last time I tried it, however it returned an issue locating perl libs, so I'm not sure what is causing it, going to reinstall my shared lib for perl and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this website to convert DOS Batch Files to Shell Scripts https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html